# Better to use include images or fonts in android?

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to android programming and was wondering if would it be better to add an image that uses a custom font, or just add the custom font and set it as the typeface of a textview? In terms of memory footprint and performance. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a .ttf file for Font is always better than to have images for texts because:

1. Less intensive on memory
2. Easy to scale text across various screen sizes, using desity independent text size units : sp

Comment: A vectorial font is scalable by definition, and doesn't require additional resources.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to use TextView. You can be certain that no matter what's yout device is if you use a TextView your app will never have all kinds of blur, visible pixels or all other stuff that you can't avoid with small images. Also you have to take care of memory. I know that it's probably small image, but when you've got a lot of them there has to be some kind of memory protection - and that is another work to do.

It's hard to find correct font size - sometimes it's all depend on your device. But that's why you have all this possibilities with different values folders. You can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Another thing is, you don't always have to put your custom font manually in every TextView.
Just extend TextView class and use like normal Android component. You can see how to do it here:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-extend-androids-textview-to-use-custom-fonts/